# Unexpected this in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, eslint, mongoose-schema

I tried ESLint for the first time, and I get an error for a code that always worked for me.
In the User schema, I am trying to encrypt user password and I get the error:

> error  Unexpected 'this'  no-invalid-this

My code is:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const user = this;

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Why is it invalid this?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-this  --- as far as I understand if you're not using it in a constructor or class then this is supposed to yell at you because it's possible `this` is `undefined`.

Comment: Just as a side comment - you do not need to set const user = this; since you are using arrow functions and the this-context will be preserved.

You can just say:  this.password = hash.

Also I would just disable that rule if it doesnt work for you